# ASP.NET ReportViewer control: make toolbar static

Tags: reportviewer, webforms, reporting-services

I am using the ReportViewer control in an ASP.NET WebForms application to display (and optionally export/print) reports. Standard stuff really.

However, my users are complaining that the toolbar scrolls with the report content: so if they want move to the next page it is necessary to scroll back to the top of the page first.

I cannot find any articles (here or elsewhere) that indicate any means of making the toolbar static (as in, the toolbar stays at the top of the page and the content of the report scrolls underneath). Can anybody here point me at a method that may allow this?

Thanks.

Comment: In case it makes a difference, I am currently using ReportViewer v10 against IE9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment against rt2800's response, the problem was related to the height set against the ReportViewer control. I resolved this with a little JavaScript that resizes the control according to the available space on the screen...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resizeFormToClientHeight() {
        var reportViewer = document.getElementById("<%= form.ClientID %>");
        form.style.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight + "px";
    }
    resizeFormToClientHeight();
    window.onresize = function resize() { resizeFormToClientHeight(); }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set AsyncRendering="True" for reportviewer? This will create a iframe into which report is rendered. This will allow the report to scroll independently. I assume ShowToolBar="true" is present in your reportviewer markup

Comment: AsyncRendering=true and ShowToolBar=true are both the default values for the control and I have left them as is. Unfortunately, this is not showing the IFrame you are expecting to be rendered. Thanks though.

Comment: belay my last repsonse; I had height set to 100% instead of a number of pixels. As soon as I changed the height of the ReportViewer control to a fixed number of pixels the scrolling started working.

Comment: I still have a problem though; when I scroll the background colour of the new content is incorrect - the background of the report should be white, but when new content scrolls into view its background is grey. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Even I make use of the report viewer control to display data on webform. However, for me the toolbar never scrolls down. I have put my reportviewer control code below. Please check if it is of any help.

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer runat="server" ID="rvData" ShowCredentialPrompts="False" ShowDocumentMapButton="False"
                ShowExportControls="true" ShowFindControls="False" ShowParameterPrompts="False"
                ShowPrintButton="true" ShowPromptAreaButton="False" ShowRefreshButton="False"
                ShowReportBody="True" ShowToolBar="true" ShowZoomControl="False" Visible="false"
                ShowPageNavigationControls="true" BackColor="#C8C8C8" LinkActiveColor="#0066CC"
                Width="100%" Height="600px">
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

If you want the report header (not the toolbar) to remain on top (freeze), I can show you how..